# URL tweets not appearing after logging in to Twitter

Tags: url, twitter

From our sites we are using Twitter to post some items, but if the user was not logged in to Twitter the supposed tweet is not carried over, instead we are directed to Twitter homepage and my tweet is forgotten. But if the user was logged in and he tweets an item it worked properly.

Do you have alternatives on this?

Comment: Please add a bit.ly/twicket

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using the API to post the tweets from your website? That would mean you could have the tweets coming from one account and you could just do it programatically.

Answer (score -1):

I havent tried it but I tried changing the Twitter URL in our codes by removing "home" from http://twitter.com/home?status=TWEET to solve the issue with the ampersand(&) leaving this URL twitter.com/?status=TWEET, twitter new version does not read ampersand so by removing "home" it resolve the issue. SO If I bring back the URL to twitter.com/home?status=TWEET it seems that it do not encounter the forgotten tweets. But it will bring back the issue with ampersand..

Any thoughts?